# Don't have permissions for anything except connecting to database in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I am trying to create a table using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. After connecting to the SQL Server Express engine, right-clicking **Databases**, clicking **New Database...**, entering a name and clicking **OK**, I get the message:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 262)

Following various posts on this site and elsewhere, I have tried the following, and each action gave me an error message saying I didn't have permission for the action:

- Adding a new login with the `dbcreator` Server Role
- Changing roles and granting privileges for `BUILTIN\Users`
- Enabling the `sa` account
- Changing the **Owned Schemas** for the `guest` user on the `master` table
- Adding a new user to the `master` table
- Doing the above steps after starting SSMS with **Run as administrator**

I have had permissions issues with MySQL in the past, and was always able to sort them out, but this is the first time I have used Microsoft SQL Server, and I am not used to developing in the Windows environment.

What do I need to do to give my Windows user (an administrator) administrative privileges for SQL Server Express?

Comment: When you installed SQL Server Express, did you add anyone to the sysadmin role? Or did you just click Next > Next > Next? Just because you are not used to developing in the Windows environment is not an excuse to not read up on it before jumping in and expecting everything to work like magic.

Comment: @AaronBertrand very true. Although I think I did do this, is there any way to a) check b) add a user to the sysadmin role if I didn't previously?

Comment: a) `SELECT name,type_desc FROM sys.server_principals WHERE principal_id IN (SELECT member_principal_id FROM sys.server_role_members
 WHERE role_principal_id = 3);` -- any rows? You should just see SA. Unfortunately without SA permissions you don't get to see who else is SA. It's kind of a chicken and egg thing. Did you set an sa password during installation? If so, did you try connecting as sa instead of with Windows auth
?

Comment: @AaronBertrand `1 | sa | SQL_LOGIN`...I guess that means that I did not set one up during installation. Is there any way I can do it now?

Comment: You need to have sa rights to create an sa account. Just like you need to be domain admin to create a domain admin. Have you tried logging in as sa instead of using your Windows account? (You would need to know the sa password you defined, and no, you can't reset it like your Yahoo password.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, that was one of the first things I tried initially, but was unable to do so. I didn't set a passoword for sa, and neither of the administrative Windows user passwords worked. I also tried setting the sa password, but didn't have permission to do so.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/argenis_fernandez/archive/2012/01/12/leveraging-service-sids-to-logon-to-sql-server-2012-instances-with-sysadmin-privileges.aspx